# Dir Function in a specific order?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA, and looping through spreadsheets in a specific folder - opening the spreadsheets, coping some lines then pasting it into a master spreadsheet. I made use of the following link to achieve the loop:

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

My problem/question: the spreadsheets have the date saved as the file name - for example:

Trader Estimate T+1 Consol_20131003.xlsx

But it seems using the Dir function, that the spreadsheets are not being opened in the chronological order as dictated by the date in the filename.

How would I achieve this opening in chronological order (according to the filename)?

Don't know if this makes a difference but the spreadsheets are not saved on this computer in chronological order - ie. if I order the folder of spreadsheets by date modified, they are not in perfect order as dictated by the date in their filename.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Should be migrated to StackOverflow (I can't choose this from the off topic migration menu, only meta is available there).

Comment: Sorry Bob, could you explain why it should be migrated to stack overflow so I do not make the same mistake in the future

Comment: This site is for professionals involved with quantitative finance. Your question is more akin to a basic programming problem which is what StackOverflow can help you with.

Comment: Dir returns files in directory order, not sorted alphabetically. You could instead read the filenames into an array and then sort the array (see reference to QuickSort below)

Answer (score 1):

My be you will find these links helpful to get started

[QuickSort](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_dir_quicksorted.html)(Get a sorted list of files in a directory using Dir and Quicksort)

Similar Question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617115/forcing-files-and-folders-to-be-dealt-with-in-alphabetical-order)